# Error with Shared Preferences across Services and Activities

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox Core API SDK to develop an Android application. I authenticate the user through an Activity A and store the token in a method M using Shared Preferences. I have a Service S, which would be responsible to upload to Dropbox and to upload, S needs access to the tokens stored in Shared Preferences.

The issue is that whenever I try to access M in A to access the tokens, I get a Null Pointer Exception.

Activity A

```
    public void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String key = prefs.getString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, null);
            String secret = prefs.getString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, null);
            if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0 || secret.length() == 0) return;
            session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);

        }



public void storeAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
        String oauth2AccessToken = session.getOAuth2AccessToken();
        if (oauth2AccessToken != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
            edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
            edit.commit();
            return;
        }
    }





public AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        loadAuth(session);
        return session;
    }
```

Service S

public class UploadService extends IntentService {

```
private static final String TAG = "UploadService";
DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi;
DropboxAuth dbAuth=new DropboxAuth();    
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        AndroidAuthSession session = dbAuth.buildSession();
        mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);}}
```

I get a Null Pointer Exception at AndroidAuthSession session = dbAuth.buildSession();
Please Help.

Comment: post code snippet where you getting problem

Comment: I have added the code segment. Please check.

Comment: From your code snippet, it seems that dbAuth is null. Have you tried debugging to find out why that is?

Comment: But it shouldn't be, because i have already authenticated to Dropbox and accessed the token.

Comment: If you're getting a NPE for dbAuth on: DropboxAuth dbAuth=new DropboxAuth();, have you checked where dbAuth is supposed to be getting created? I.e.: DropboxAuth dbAuth=new DropboxAuth(); You haven't posted the constructor for DropboxAuth so it's unclear what's happening there.